# First cell is writable in Janus GridEx for Winforms, even though the grid is read-only

Tags: janus, gridex

I have a strange problem with the `Janus GridEx` for Winforms, and hope someone who uses it and may encountered some similar problem can help me.

I have a read-only grid, which contains a group of notification entities, and the grid itself is contained inside a window which pops up every time a new notification arrives for the specific client.

When the window is loaded, the focus is set to the grid, and when I type something on the keyboard, it shows the text in the first cell of the first row and column, even though all the grid is readonly.

Only when I click on another window or on some other row, it stops receiving my keystrokes.
I tried everything I could think of, including programmatically move the focus to another control, and move it back to the first row of the grid, sending a left-click message on the window and many more things. Nothing works, and if I put a breakpoint in an event which catches keystrokes on the grid, the program doesn't stop on this breakpoint.

Did someone encountered something similar with the grid?

I know it's too little information, and I can't provide some code here, because the project is in a separate network, and I also can't point out on some specific method which causes the strange behaviour and copy it to this message.

P.S I write in C#.

I will be glad if in any chance someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting GridEx's `AllowAddNew`, `AllowEdit` and `AllowDelete` properties to the following:

```
grdEx.AllowAddNew = Janus.Windows.GridEX.InheritableBoolean.False;
grdEx.AllowEdit = Janus.Windows.GridEX.InheritableBoolean.False;
grdEx.AllowDelete = Janus.Windows.GridEX.InheritableBoolean.False;
```